# Connection between t and F distributions

Tags: distributions, self-study, t-distribution, f-distribution

We have:
$Z\sim N_{0,1}$ (standard normal distribution) , $U\sim X^2_{k}$ ($X^2$ distribution, with k df) with $Z \bot U$

Then $X = \frac{Z}{ \sqrt{U  /k} } \sim t (k)$ (t-distribution, with k df)

I am missing how $X^2 \sim F(1,k)$

Comment: Puzzled by your difficulty. $X^2 = \frac{Z^2}{(U/k)},$ where $Z^2$ is CHISQ(1) (divided by its DF=1) and the denominator is independently CHISQ(k) (divided by its DF=k); that is the definition of F(1,k). If you don't understand _why_ this is the answer, please be explicit.

Comment: This search found an answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=F+t+test+normal+distribution+p-value+answers%3A1

Comment: We have the $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, t-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and  F-distribution with parameters $d_1$ and $d_2$


$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\chi^2_{n} &=& \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 \\
T_n &=& \frac{Z}{\sqrt{\chi_n/n}} &=& \frac{Z_{n+1}}{ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2}}\\ 
F_{d_1,d_2}  &=& \frac{\chi_{d_1}/d_1}{\chi_{d_2}/d_2} &= & \frac{\frac{1}{d_1} \sum_{i=d_2+1}^{d_2+d_1} Z_i^2}{  \frac{1}{d_2} \sum_{i=1}^{d_2} Z_i^2}\\ 
\end{array}$$

Comment: So the square of $T_1$

$$(T_1)^2 = \frac{Z_{n+1}^2}{{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2}} $$

Looks very much like $F_{1,n}$


$$F_{1,n} =  \frac{\frac{1}{1} \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1} Z_i^2}{  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2} = \frac{ Z_{n+1}^2}{  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2} $$

The t-distribution, when you square it then the square root term $\sqrt{\chi_n/n}$ in the denominator turns into a $\chi_n \frac{1}{n}$ term, and the numerator, a normal distributed variable, turns into the square of a normal distributed variable, which is a $\chi_1$ term.

Comment: These are some very good answers. Thank you